# Is Jellal really married? Who's his wife?

Tags: fairy-tail

I'm far back and trying to catch up in the series, but as most people confused who are at the same place as me ( On the beach with Jellal and Erza) who really is Jellal's wife?

Comment: Huh? Is Jellal married?

Comment: Aki Tanaka He said he was married either to stop Erza from kissing him or he really was married. I have no idea to be honest.

Comment: Better put that in the question to add some background (also, from which chapter/episode), and possibly change the title to "Is Jellal really married? Who's the wife?"

Answer (score 0):

My friend, you shouldn't ask for things that will produce spoilers. I know the arc that your're referring to and if you really REALLY want to know then reveal the spoiler below. But I would encourage you to just keep watching.

> Jellal is not married, this is brought to light later. He said that to her to keep his emotions in check so that he could focus on the mission.